# Merge bitwise permission

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a user that has 2 role, each role have a permission value. 
For example:
User ABC who have 2 role: role A, role B

- role A:

  - Edit : 1
  - Delete : 2
    => permission number for role A is 3
- role B:

  - Delete : 2
  - Update : 8 
    => permission number for role B is 10

So, I want to get permission number for user A, expected value is 
(1 + 2 + 8) = 11

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [| (bitwise or) operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx):

```
int a = 3;
int b = 10;
int c = a | b;
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

This prints out "11".

> For integral types, | computes the bitwise OR of its operands